# Google Cloud VPN - Egress from GCP to on-premise pricing clarification

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vpn

Considering the Google Cloud VPN for networking Google Cloud platform to On-premise as per the following
https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/overview

Given that the Cloud VPN tunnel connects to a gateway in GCP, below is the pricing for egress - https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#general

I would like to know what would be the exact cost for egressing from GCP to the on-premise server on that case based on different line items present in the pricing above. Would the regular 'internet egress rates' apply for my usecase?

Answer (score 1):

IPsec traffic are charged as if the traffic were regular egress traffic.

There could be two scenerios:

1.If the Cloud VPN tunnel connects to a gateway in GCP, egress pricing to the region containing that gateway applies as per [general network pricing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#general).

2.If the Cloud VPN tunnel connects to a gateway outside of GCP, [Internet egress rates](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#internet_egress) apply.

Answer (score -2):

GCP VPN pricing is very confusing. I wrote a calculator to make it easier to estimate that can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LjZ10Bc9Zr7GUhq2UqTDYKvSLjRZGwrCCnZftccFPuk/edit#gid=1818588508). There is also a full write up explaining their pricing [here](https://www.twingate.com/blog/google-cloud-vpn-pricing/).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).